# Open a .py file in HTML using a link / button

Tags: python, html, file

So I'm creating a website and I was wondering if I could create a button / link to open a FILE, not another website, but a .py file. -Thanks

Comment: What you mean by "open a .py file in HTML"? Do you mean "open a .py file in the default web browser"? And what exactly is your difficulty--creating the button/link, responding to a click of that button or link, or opening the file? Finally, which do you want, a button and a link? The are quite different in setup. If a button, which environment are you using?

Comment: Well yes, the default browser, but to answer your question, my difficulty is NOT KNOWING HOW.

Comment: Not know how to do what? You answered only my first question.

Comment: IM NOT HAVING DIFFICULTY WITH ANYTHING, I DON'T KNOW HOW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have **object** tag in html. You create one button and an object. When u click on the button then you have to change the data attribute value of object tag. 
It will work.

Comment: Do you know how I would apply that to my file problem ? - Thanks

Comment: Do u want to run the code and display the output of the code. Or u want to display the code inside the .py file

Comment: Inside the .py file.

Comment: `<html >
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="$('object').attr('data','script.py');" value="Show .Py File">
    
<object width="400" height="400" data="#">
</object>
 
</body>
</html>
`

Comment: I don't know much html, what is the data type and what do I fill in with what ? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use any lightweight python web framework like Flask.

Then use a script like this to run it on a website:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():  
    #do your things here
    return "It works!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Then run the server :
python script. py

Now the server is running on port 5000

So when you visit (eg: http://rasp_pi_ip:5000/) the website, your script will run.

Comment: Do I run this on the python, HTML, or JavaScript ?

Comment: You run this is Python

Comment: How do I use it  ? Like what do I fill in and how do I use it ? -  Thanks